# warning while passing a string in c function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a function that will pass a string and manipulate. in the function call i am passing the string as such like `myfunc ("hello");`

In the function definition i have

```
myfunc (char *array)
{
    xxxx
};
```

The program is working fine, but it throws a warning "pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'myfunc' differ in signedness".

How to rectify this problem?

Comment: C or C++? The answer is the same, but the technicalities are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are actually arrays of *constant* characters. That is, the type of `"hello"` is `const char[6]`.

What this means is you cannot modify it. However, due to a silly conversion in C++, the array (in string literal form) can be implicitly converted to a *non-const* pointer to the first element. This is misleading, and dangerous. (Indeed, a const-stripping implicit conversion  doesn't exist anywhere else.)

You should make sure you have a modifiable buffer instead:

```
char buffer[] = "hello";
myfunc(buffer);
```

Comment: I think the warning is because the compiler might be treating `char` as unsigned at one point and signed at another. I am not very sure.

Comment: @Prasoon: Oh, probably. (I actually skimmed the question, working on getting as lazy as possible while still earning reputation. :))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your definition for `myfunc()` function has `char*` as parameter. I think, it has unsigned char* as parameter. or somewhere else in your code, you are passing `unsigned char*` as argument to `myfunc(char*)`. Look at the warning line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

what if you declare your function like `myfunc (const char *array)`

Answer (score 0):

I think Prasoon is right. Your compiler is treating "string literals" as `unsigned char`. Just change your function to accept `unsigned char` ...or change the compiler setting which decides if a "string literal" is signed/unsigned.